# What directive can I give a stream to print leading zeros on a number in C++?

Tags: c++, formatting, zero, clog, leading-zero

I know how to cause it to be in hex:

```
unsigned char myNum = 0xA7;
clog << "Output: " std::hex << int(myNum) << endl;
// Gives:
//   Output: A7
```

Now I want it to always print a leading zero if myNum only requires one digit:

```
unsigned char myNum = 0x8;
// Pretend std::hex takes an argument to specify number of digits.
clog << "Output: " << std::hex(2) << int(myNum) << endl;
// Desired:
//   Output: 08
```

So how can I actually do this?

Comment: You do realize that anyone trying to read your hex numbers back in will see them as octal numbers? Just asking.:-)

Comment: True, but this is for human consumption, not computer consumption.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not as clean as I'd like, but you can change the "fill" character to a '0' to do the job:

```
your_stream << std::setw(2) << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << x;
```

Note, however, that the character you set for the fill is "sticky", so it'll stay '0' after doing this until you restore it to a space with something like `your_stream << std::setfill(' ');`.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x = 0x23;
  cout << "output: " << setfill('0') << setw(3) << hex << x << endl;
}
```

output: 023

Answer (score 1):

```
glog << "Output: " << std::setfill('0') << std::hex(2) << int(myNum) << endl;
```

See also: http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `setfill` and `setw` manipulators in <iomanip>

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit dirty, but a macro did a good job for me:

```
#define fhex(_v) std::setw(_v) << std::hex << std::setfill('0')
```

So then you can do it:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
...
int value = 0x12345;
cout << "My Hex Value = 0x" << fhex(8) << value << endl;
```

The output:

> My Hex Value = 0x00012345